# Knockout.js 'enable' binding hides button element in IE8

Tags: javascript, html, css, knockout.js, internet-explorer-8

This is really weird behavior that my website is displaying, but here is the description (I'll describe it as best as possible, it is part of a much larger web based application):

I have a page that lets the user create, read, update, delete filters for customers (i.e. age, household size, etc)

The form is dynamically populated (using ajax), which is effectively generated using knockouts foreach binding (there are several of these forms generated based on the ajax request and the number of filters).

One of the things that happens when a user is updating a filter is a bit of validation happens (is the date a date, is the household size a number, etc), and then a save button and a cancel button are displayed.

Both buttons are hidden by CSS initially, then when a filter is edited, both buttons are made visible and knockouts enable binding is used to enable/disable the save button depending on whether the validation passes/fails, in realtime using knockout. (we have server side validation too, but that does not relate to this issue).

This all works fine in all browsers save for IE8 (which is a must have supported browser for this web app for our client).

When validation fails in IE8, the save button is disabled as per usual, but it is still hidden from the page until the user moves his mouse a few pixels.

```
<div id="filter-editor" class="menu-list" data-bind="foreach: filters">
  <form class="form-inline new-filter-form">
    <select class="input-medium" data-bind="options: $root.fields, optionsText: 'name', value: attribute"></select>
    <select class="input-small" data-bind="options: $root.getFilteredOperators($data), optionsText: 'symbol', optionsValue: 'index', optionsCaption: 'Choose...', value: operator"></select>
    <input type="text" class="input-small editable editing"
data-bind="css: {'invalid': !isValid()}, value: value,  valueUpdate: ['keyup']"/>
    <span data-bind="css: {'hidden': !isDirty()}">
      <button class="btn btn-small btn-success" title="Save changes" data-bind="enable: isValid, click: $root.saveCondition.bind(null, $parent, $data)">Save</button>&nbsp;
      <button class="btn btn-small" title="Cancel changes" data-bind="click: $root.cancelConditionEdit.bind(null, $parent, $data)">Cancel</button>
    </span>
  </form>
</div>
```

The isValid() method returns true/false (boolean), this then enables/disables the button. I cannot see why the button would be hidden from view until the mouse moves. We have no mouseevents attached anywhere. Any suggestions?

EDIT:
I have had some success in getting the button to display in IE8 consistently. I added a 'css' binding to the save button, and that forces the button to always display, regardless of whether it has a disabled or enabled attribute applied.

```
<button class="btn btn-small btn-success" title="Save changes" data-bind="css: {'blah': 'blah'}, enable: isValid, click: $root.saveCondition.bind(null, $parent, $data)">Save</button>
```

However, it appears that the CSS binding is just causing the DOM to update, even if I put nonsensical attributes and values in there. This is a quick fix, but why is this happening on IE8 and why does the CSS binding fix it?

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap? Try removing the styles and see if it works. Knockout bindings work only with standard controls.

Comment: I am using bootstrap, but all of the code works cross-browser, except for this IE8 only glitch.

Comment: Look for the order of your data-bind tokens I'd read somewhere that some can be evaluated in a particular order and could lead to incorrect behavior

Answer (score 0):

try enclosing all the bindings in quotes in this way:

```
<button class="btn btn-small btn-success" title="Save changes" data-bind="'css': {'blah': 'blah'}, 'enable': isValid, 'click': $root.saveCondition.bind(null, $parent, $data)">Save</button>
```

IE8 does not like knockout a lot so this may solve some issues.

Comment: Good suggestion, but the issue is that when I leave the css data-binding out, the save button is completely hidden when disabled (i.e. via knockouts enable binding). When the user moves the mouse a few pixels, IE8/knockout seems to refresh the DOM and disabled button is shown, in its disabled state. The CSS binding, somehow eliminates this problem, as long as its put in (even with nonsense values), the button is shown in its disabled state and not hidden away at all - which is what should be happening. That CSS binding is key to the fix.

Comment: try to eliminate all the data- atributes and put them back one at a time until you find which one is giving problems. I had the same problem and it was a knockout 'while' that ie8 didn't like. This can be a completely random bind that create the problem, and the css stop the problem only because it changes the rules somehow.